# Why does "save %test.png make image! [1024x768]" causes a Seg Fault?

Tags: raspberry-pi, rebol, raspbian, rebol3

I am using Rebol3 (Version: 2.101.0.4.20) on my RaspberryPi and each time I try to save an image to the filesystem it crashes with a Seg Fault:

```
save %test.png make image! [1024x768]
```

Can someone explain why? Any hints to solve this?

Comment: I don't have a RaspberryPi so I can't test, but others have them.  Is it the save that causes the problem, or the `make image`?  If you reduce it down to say a 1x1 image is it still a problem?  What directory are you in, and do ordinary saves (such as text files) work?

Comment: Yes, it is the save that causes the problem. I'll check later if saving smaller images or ordinary saves causes a Seg Fault too. The working directory is beneath /home/pi and r3 has been started as user pi.

Comment: I'll do some testing with my pi (running raspbmc) and let you know if the behaviour is the same. Have you tried with `trace on` to see if you can see what happens just before the crash?

Comment: could it be a missing or incompatible png library on the os?

Comment: Checked again with `trace on`. It seems that `do-decode` causes the segmentation fault. @johnk thanx for the bitmap file work around.

Comment: Is JPEG a valid filetype for save? On RasPi .jpg fails too:
`>> save %test.jpg make image! [1024x768]`
`** Access error: bad media data (corrupt image, sound, video)`
`** Where: do-codec all encode if save`
`** Near: do-codec cod/entry 'encode data`

Comment: I raised a bug for this on curecode http://curecode.org/rebol3/ticket.rsp?id=2040 It looks like there are jpeg problems as well (at least no segfault).  Moliad - I had a quick look at the source and this is all pure rebol c code, no dependencies.

Comment: FYI there is an active Rebol chat room in this stack overflow site http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/291/rebol-and-red

Answer (score 3):

Seems to be a Rebol 3 linux bug as this works fine under Windows. Reproduced on x86 linux and raspberry pi. As a possible work around you can generate `bmp` files correctly.

`save %test.bmp make image! [1024x768]`

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, I just tried this on Atronix's recent build running on Ubuntu 16.04 on an ODROID-C1+ ARM/Linux board:

**    Version:   3.0.99.4.20                                            **
**    Platform:  Linux libc6-arm                                        **
**    Build:     20-Jul-2018/19:57:26                                   **

I was able to save PNG and BMP files using 'to-image on a gob! and also using 'make image! [1024x768]